# sum() error, unsupported operant type int and nonetype

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the advent of code day 2 and am running in an error when i try to do the sum to find the sum for rock paper scissors:

```
map_input = {'A': 'Rock', 'B': 'Paper', 'C': 'Scissors', 'X': 'Rock', 'Y': 'Paper', 'Z': 'Scissors'}
points_per_shape = {'Rock': 1, 'Paper': 2, 'Scissors': 3}
points_per_outcome = {'Lose': 0, 'Draw': 3, 'Win': 6}



with open(r'C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive\Documents\advent of code\day 2\input.in') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    rounds = [entry.strip() for entry in lines]

def points_per_round(round_string):
    opponent_shape = map_input[round_string[0]] #opponent, first character
    our_shape = map_input[round_string[2]] #me, second character

    if opponent_shape == our_shape:
        return points_per_outcome['Draw'] + points_per_shape[our_shape]
    elif (opponent_shape, our_shape) in [('Paper', 'Rock'), ('Rock', 'Scissors'), ('Scissors, Paper')]:
        return points_per_outcome['Lose'] + points_per_shape[our_shape]
    elif (opponent_shape, our_shape) in [('Rock', 'Paper'), ('Scissors', 'Rock'), ('Paper', 'Scissors')]:   
        return points_per_outcome['Win'] + points_per_shape[our_shape]
        
    
total = sum([points_per_round(round_string) for round_string in rounds])
print(total)
```

the file in question being like this
B X
A Z
A Y

continuing like this for thousands of rows

i get this error when i try to run the code, but dont get any if i replace the last line from the elif to elsee, but get the wrong answer with it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\my_name\OneDrive\Documents\advent of code\day 2\rock paper scissors.py", line 23, in <module>
    total = sum([points_per_round(round_string) for round_string in rounds])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

i get this error when i try to run the code, but dont get any if i replace the last line from the elif to elsee, but get the wrong answer with it

Comment: Under certain circumstances, *points_per_round()* is (implicitly) returning None. You'll need to debug that function

Comment: if none of your if/elif cases applies, your program returns None (instance of NoneType).  sum() uses a + operator, which cannot add None to a number. You need to specify what to do if none of the cases apply. for example, add ```else: return 0```

Answer (score 2):

In the first `elif` there is a typo:

```py
elif (opponent_shape, our_shape) in [('Paper', 'Rock'), ('Rock', 'Scissors'), ('Scissors, Paper')]
```

should be

```py
elif (opponent_shape, our_shape) in [('Paper', 'Rock'), ('Rock', 'Scissors'), ('Scissors', 'Paper')]
```

notice the last example in your code is a tuple containing a single string with the text `Scissors, Paper`, instead it should be a tuple containing two strings, one with the text `Scissors` and one with the text `Paper`.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the last line is empty, so you may use array's `pop()` method to remove the last line of the `lines`

Answer (score 0):

Summing up what the others already pointed out:

1. You got a typo in your first `elif` statement `('Scissors, Paper')` instead of `('Scissors', 'Paper')`
2. Your `if` loop can implicitly return `None` if none of the conditions is met. This is probably what happens due to your typo. Consider adding an `else` statement to explicitly return a useful value or throwing an error like `Didn't match any of the conditions`